# SQL-Server 2008: How to update fields with a counter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

On PostgrSQL its no problem for me to do this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE serial_olw START 1;
update collections_elements set elementorder=(nextval('serial_olw')-1) WHERE collections_elements.collectionid=1;
drop sequence serial_olw;
```

Example: 1,2,3,4,5,6...

On a MS-SQL Server 2008 there is not a function SEQUENCE... so I tried this:

```
DECLARE @i int
SET @i = 0

WHILE @i<44
    BEGIN
    UPDATE collections_elements set elementorder=(@i) WHERE collections_elements.collectionid=1
        SET @i=@i+1
    END
```

But I have no success  with that loop...

Example: 43,43,43,43,43...

Any ideas for a solution?

Comment: You are updating all records on every loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Update t
Set t.elementorder = t.RowID
From
(
    Select ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order by collectionid) as RowID, * From collections_elements
)t
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2350/3)**

Comment: The same problem... 43,43,43,43

Answer (score 1):

```
update T
set elementorder = rn
from
  (
    select elementorder,
           row_number() over(order by (select 0)) as rn
    from collections_elements
    where collectionid = 1
  ) T
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/71125)

Comment: Hey, didn't know plain subselects could be updatable too! Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this - inline variable increment:

```
DECLARE @i int 
SET @i = 0

WHILE @i<44 
BEGIN
    UPDATE collections_elements 
    SET @i = elementorder = @i + 1 
    WHERE collections_elements.collectionid=1 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

this script is a sample.
Try something like this - inline variable increment:

```
DECLARE @i int 
SET @i = 1 

BEGIN
    UPDATE Questionnaire 
    SET prioritize = @i 
    ,  @i = @i +1 
    WHERE documentTypeCode=2 and groupCode=02
END
```